# what categories do relational languages describe?

Tags: prolog, computer-science, category-theory, logic-programming, minikanren

I read that lambda calculus is the language of cartesian closed categories.

As I understand it, relational languages such as minikanren or (in part) prolog would then operate on those, but also other categories (since functions are a special case of relations). Knowing more about that would help me understand what those languages can do for me that others cannot.

So what categories do relational languages describe?